# Mbed OS 5 Analog Pulse Counter using STM32L432

Tags: c++, stm32, mbed

Is there a good method for **counting Sine Waves using Mbed OS 5**?
As far as I'm concerned, the API only provides an elegant solution to this using **InterruptIn** for Digital signals.

From experience with AVR controllers, **input capture** modes allow for edge detection using Timer/Counters.

In my case, there is no need for any timing nor frequency measurements.

I've tried using both InterruptIn and AnalogIn with a set threshold but seem to get burst of counted values rather than **Single Pulse Counting**.

Comment: Question about counting Sine Waves is unrelated to Mbed OS and stm32. You shoud accumulate data from `AnalogIn` and handle this array of data. It is like you can have several different sources of data: ADC, stream from network, text file etc. And method of handling is common for all sources.

So. You can create 2 questions: how to accumulate data and how extract sine from data.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but are you familiar with the Mbed OS5 API? I am looking for a solution such as *InterruptIn* only for Analog signals in Real-time.